# Issues with running Apache Certbot due to port already used for httpd.bin

Tags: 14.04, apache2, process, ssl, letsencrypt

My goal is to get SSL running on my server to run over HTTPS. I'm trying to run the command `sudo certbot --apache` to generate a certificate for my server as part of these steps https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntutrusty-apache.

I'm having issues with this, as when I run the command I get the error

```
Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
```

When I check what is running on port 80, I see httpd.bin.

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1372/httpd.bin
```

But httpd.bin is said to not be running in the error message above. I have tried to kill the process running on port 80, but have been unable to. I've also tried to locate the PID of the Apache parent process (http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26130&seqNum=3) however, I do not have /acpache directory in usr/local.

How should I proceed with killing the process? - Should I be focusing on killing this process, or is there another way around this issue?

The other confusing thing is that when I run sudo service apache2 status the result is apache2 is not running but I cannot start this process either as port 80 is in use (not sure if Apache2 is required in my scenario.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Currently `letsencrypt`/`certbot` with `--apache` option doesn't work as it is expected. There are some changes that should be applied to the CertBot's mechanism that interact with Apache, but they are not applied yet. I couldn't found the exact article that I've read in January 2018, when I found this issue.

You can use `letsencrypt`/`certbot` with the option `certonly`. With this option the tool will start its own temporal web server to generate the certificate files. Ports `80` and `443` should be open in your firewall. 
 And you should stop Apache for a while. Unfortunately you should do this when you `renew` the certificates.

```bsh
sudo service apache2 stop           # Ubuntu 14.04
sudo systemctl stop apache2.service # Ubuntu 16.04 and above

sudo letsencrypt certonly --rsa-key-size 4096 --email user@example.com -d example.com -d www.example.com -d another.example.com
# Select the option: Automatically use temporary web server (standalone)

sudo service apache2 start           # Ubuntu 14.04
sudo systemctl start apache2.service # Ubuntu 16.04 and above
```

Then you need to edit by hand your virtual host's configuration file. Here is an example with permanent redirection from HTTP to HTTPS (replace `example.com` with your FQDN):

```bsh
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com

        # Redirect Requests to HTTPS
        Redirect permanent / https://example.com/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory /var/www/html>
            # Conf directives...
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.ssl.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.ssl.access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Enable the SSL module for Apache and restart it once again.

References:

- [Automatically enable HTTPS on your website with EFF's Certbot, deploying Let's Encrypt certificates: Apache on Ubuntu.](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntutrusty-apache)

Hope this help!