# I can't restart the apace2 if I open the SSL port 443 in file of `/etc/apache2/ports.conf ` in ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: server, 18.04, apache2, services, ssl

I get a problem in `18.04`.I want to configure the SSL for my website, so I edit the profile in `etc/apache2/ports.conf` and add the line like `Listen 443`, but when I do `service apache2 restart` the apahce service can't be restarted but it just work fine in `16.04` like that.Then I delete the line `Listen 443` and the Apache service works again..

It says:`Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

`journalctl -xe`:

```
 ubuntu apachectl[2867]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 8 of /etc/apache2/ports.conf:
 ubuntu apachectl[2867]: Cannot define multiple Listeners on the same IP:port
 ubuntu apachectl[2867]: Action 'start' failed.
 ubuntu apachectl[2867]: The Apache error log may have more information.
 ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
 ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

The line 8 is just what I add..
It dose work in `16.04` if I do the same thing, I want to know is anything changed in `18.04`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've conducted a small investigation - yes there is a different behaviour between Apache2's versions that come with Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 18.04.

- **16.04** comes with **Apache/2.4.18** and there is no matter how many times you will repeat identical Listen directives - I've tested that on a virtual machine.
- **18.04** comes with **Apache/2.4.29** and in the [current Apache2.4 documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) is written:

  > **Error condition**
  >
  > Multiple Listen directives for the same ip address and port will result in an Address already in use error message.

In your case the directive `Listen 443` appears twice within the Apache's configuration, so according to these new rules it is normal to receive the above error.

By default, within `ports.conf`, the directive `Listen 443` is enclosed with `<IfModule>` tags, as follow:

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

That means it will be active only when `mod_ssl` (or `mod_gnutls`) is enabled. So, if you have enabled `mod_ssl`, you do not need to put any additional `Listen 443`.

---

You can investigate how many times and where the directive `Listen 443` appears in your configuration by the command:

```
grep -rni 'listen 443' /etc/apache2/
```

You can check which Apache's modules are enabled by the command(s):

```
sudo apachectl -M
sudo apachectl -M | grep 'ssl\|tls'
```

You can check whether any service listen to port 443 and which is it by the commands:

```
sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep ':443'
sudo netstat -peanut | grep ':443'
```

Further reading: [How to secure Apache with Let's Encrypt](https://askubuntu.com/a/1034358/566421).

Comment: Thank you,it just like you say I enable the `mod_ssl`.But I enable the mod_ssl and add the line `Listen 443` at the same time in 16.04 it just work fine.So I'm not sure if someting has changed in 18.04 at this point.By the way,I want to know  do `Listen 443` and the `mod_ssl` make the same  effect on the SSL configuration so that I can just open one of them,thanks.

Comment: @OBENMO, you are right. There is a difference, I've rewrote my answer.

Comment: @OBENMO: If [this] answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) (by click on the grey tick ✓ left to it) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out. This is also a part of the mechanism that makes StackExchange format to work so nice.

Comment: Oh sry.I'm new here. I marked it just now ;-)