# How to get a more verbose error message with service apache2 start

Tags: server, 20.04, apache2

I have the task to transfer apache settings from an old linux system to a new system (Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS).
After copying the /etc/apache2 folders to the new server and restarting the apache I had some problems which were caused by missing libraries in the config files. I fixed those and

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl -t
Syntax OK
```

gives me the ok on my configuration files.

However when I try to start the apache again this happens:

```
$ sudo service apache2 start
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

journalctl -xe has nothing and v goves me the following:

```
$ systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-10-13 16:05:54 UTC; 50s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 41669 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

So the informations basically "you have an error because you have an error"

How can I get the apache start more verbose to get hints what the problem might be?

I already had a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117262/ubuntu-18-04-error-with-apache2)

Comment: Use the journal.  `journalctl -u apache2.service -n 50` should get you the lines you want to look at, and is a more accurate form of journalctl that gets you Apache data.  This is where you'll find error output;

Comment: @David regrettably I am not the "real" admin of this system and also not the person allowed to make the decisions. 
If that were the case I would e.g. install the 289 security updates on the other server, which is an 16.04. 

It is a poor company, when a developer is more competent in apache adminstration as the responsible admin. 

In short: Yes you are right, I wish I could.

Comment: @ThomasWard thank you that helped!

...

Oct 13 16:02:43 gl-p-euw4a-pucintra5 apachectl[41648]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Oct 13 16:02:43 gl-p-euw4a-pucintra5 apachectl[41648]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Oct 13 16:02:43 gl-p-euw4a-pucintra5 apachectl[41645]: Action 'start' failed.
Oct 13 16:02:43 gl-p-euw4a-pucintra5 apachectl[41645]: The Apache error log may have more information.

Although it is poetry that it first says it cannot open the logs and the advises me to look in the logs :D But I guess this is my error!

Comment: @ThomasWard do you want to post this as an answer?

Comment: yep i'll do so.

Comment: Thank you @Calamity Jane I see there was nothing wrong with my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the recommendations by systemd in 20.04 and elsewhere is that you're not guaranteed to get data in the logs that's useful with those.  `journalctl -xe` includes extra noise and junk not related to Apache, and `systemctl status` will only get you the last run/load stanza which will not give you useful information.

To really find out what you're having a problem with, you need to use `journalctl` but with different options.  Run `journalctl -u apache2.service -n 50` to get the last 50 lines from the journal logs.  Increase that number `50` to however many lines oyu need to get the error messages.

(Note that in 22.04 and later, the systemd error output indicates to add `u` to the arguments and specify the service that failed to get service-specific logs.)

---

from your comments you indicated you found these errors following these instructions:

```
Oct 13 16:02:43 gl-p-euw4a-pucintra5 apachectl[41648]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Oct 13 16:02:43 gl-p-euw4a-pucintra5 apachectl[41648]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Oct 13 16:02:43 gl-p-euw4a-pucintra5 apachectl[41645]: Action 'start' failed.
Oct 13 16:02:43 gl-p-euw4a-pucintra5 apachectl[41645]: The Apache error log may have more information.
```

You can chase that error down in separate discussion threads here or simple Google, but at least you know the error you're running into now!